# How can I mask outputs as "not-available / don't train" in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Assume I have a network which should learn two different tasks, e.g. recognizing if an image contains a cat, a dog or both. Let's say we have only some of the labels. So for some images we know there is a cat, for some we know there is no cat, for some we know there is a dog and for some we know there is no dog. The labels then look like this (dogs first, cats second):

```
[[None, 1]. [None, 0], [None, 0], [1, None], ...]
```

meaning

- for the first entry we know that a cat is present, but we don't know if there is a dog
- for the second entry we know there is no cat, but we don't know if there is a dog.
- for the third entry we know there is no cat, but we don't know if there is a dog.
- for the forth entry we know it is a dog, but not if there is a cat or not.

Of course those labels can easily be split in two parts:

- labels: `[[-1, 1]. [-1, 0], [-1, 0], [1, -1], ...]`
- mask: `[[1, 0]. [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], ...]` - part that should be ignored for gradient calculation.

How can I mask the gradient for those kinds of labels, so that it doesn't try to learn when there is `None`?

Comment: will it affect the learning a lot if you transform "there is no cat" into "this is no cat" --> so turning `None` to `0` e.g.?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Assume there is a cat. Maybe even in 60% of the cases. Then you tell the network in 60% the cases wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `mask` is a tensor with shape `(batch_size, 2)`, and that `mask[i, j]` is 0 if the `j`-th label for the `i`-th example is undefined, and 1 otherwise. Then, to mask the gradient, you could define your loss function as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(mask):
    # Mask: tensor with shape=(None, 2)
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(mask * K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))
    return loss
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.